# Branch.io Links using the HTTP API

Tags: android, branch.io

I am trying to link a user to my application by sending a Branch.io URL. On clicking the URL, the app will open if it is already installed else it will open the PlayStore. However, on clicking the link it always opens the Play Store in the browser. The link is made on our server using the HTTP API. The parameters that are set are as follows:

```
"data":"{\"phonenumber\":\"9112345678\", \"email\":\"sidrama@gmail.com\", \"referralCode\":\"331852\", \"$android_url\":\"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile.ict.cart\", \"$android_deeplink_path\":\"lokacart://\", \"$android_uri_scheme\":\"lokacart://\", \"$android_package_name\":\"com.mobile.ict.cart\"}"
```

I tried using the auto generated link that is given to test the setup on the Dashboard. That seems to work and opens the app. Is there any parameter I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here:

The data you associate with the link in most cases actually shouldn’t have any impact on whether the app opens or not. There might be some other configuration issue going on though. Could share the specific links generated via the Branch Dashboard and the HTTP API? If you need to keep those private, feel free to submit a support question instead: https://support.branch.io

Comment: Thanks! It was a configuration issue. I had refreshed the keys and had not changed it in my code.

Comment: Ah! Yes, that would do it. Glad you got the issue figured out!